# How can I store a 16 bit number in two bytes of char array?

Tags: c, arrays, sockets, network-programming

I need to store a port number in a char array so that it can be written to a socket. The protocol specifies that bytes 25 and 26 are for the port number. I have tried a variety of things but this is what I have now to store the number:

```
//msg is declared as char msg[50];
msg[25] = (uint8_t) (UDP_PORT / 256);
msg[26] = (uint8_t) (UDP_PORT % 256);
```

Then to recover the number on the other side of the socket I have:

```
uint8_t msb, lsb;
msb = msg[25];
lsb = msg[26];
int port =  msb * 256 + lsb;
```

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Seems about right. What were you hoping for?

Comment: At the other side I get weird numbers that are pretty close to the actual port numbers.

Comment: Can you give us sample input and output?

Comment: If I were you, I'd verify that `msg[25]` and `msg[26]` when they arrive at the receiving end are the two values that you've set in `msg[25] = ...` and `msg[26] = ...`, i.e. there's no corruption in-between.

Comment: maybe post the port you tried to send and the value of the port you've decoded? I'd hazard that your message is slightly offset (i.e. you are not really decoding bytes 25/26)

Comment: Well I should be getting 20343 but instead I get 20224.

Comment: That output indicates that your lsb byte is zero. When you say bytes 25 & 26, do you mean INDEX 25 & 26 or the actual byte positions? If the latter case, you should use msg[24] and msg[25].

Comment: Thank you so much DanR I found the problem: write(PEERS[i].fd, msg, 26); should be 27

Comment: As a side note, why not use the appropriate header files for creating/manipulating packet data? ip.h / udp.h &c?

Comment: It is a school project, so I have no choice.

Comment: so you can't do something like `memcpy(msg + 25, htons(UDP_PORT), 2)`?

Comment: I was using memcpy before, but it didn't work so I tried it this way. But like I said the problem was me miscounting the number of bytes to write, not this part of the code.

Comment: @rosb: well, I wasn't trying to make a point about `memcpy`, but about `htons` and related functions.

Comment: I see, yea I really should be using htons and ntohs, but I know its only going to run on Linux machines.

Comment: @ninjalj: You can't use `htons(UDP_PORT)` as the second parameter of `memcpy()`, it should be a pointer.

Comment: @caf: ah yes, thinko, should have a uint16_t temp variable there.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried, shift, and and or operations?

```
msg[25] = (uint8_t) ((UDP_PORT >> 8) & 0xff);
msg[26] = (uint8_t) (UDP_PORT & 0xff);
```

and then

```
uint8_t msb, lsb;
msb = msg[25];
lsb = msg[26];
int port =  (msb << 8) | lsb;
```

Are you sure the UDP_PORT is a 16-bit value? ...because if it is 32-bit, the devision will not work to isolate the msb.  Of course the bit-wise operations would.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you should be using a bitwise **and** in the top fragment of code.

Comment: I'm sure you mean `&` instead of `|` in the encoding part.

Comment: In IPv4, port numbers always fit in 16 bits.

Comment: Yes, yes, sorry... how embarrassing, the ors (|) should be ands (&). I agree with the port numbers being 16 bits, but of what type is UDP_PORT?

Comment: @BrianMcFarland: In IPv4, there are no port numbers. They are an UDP/TCP concept.

Comment: @ninjalj, good call.  Brain fart on my part.    Jaco, UDP_PORT is likely to be a macro which is really the same as saying it's a literal as far as the compiler is concerned.  Anyway, he seems to have found the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Most protocols that send an integer in a multibyte binary format will send the value in network byte order for consistency across platform boundaries.  Use the socket API's `htons()` and `ntohs()` functions to convert your integer between host byte order (what the local machine natively uses) and network byte order, eg:

Sending:

```
uint16_t *ptr = (uint16_t*) &msg[25];
*ptr = htons(UDP_PORT);
```

Receiving:

```
uint16_t *ptr = (uint16_t*) &msg[25]; 
int port = ntohs(*ptr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you want:

```
/* if UDP_PORT is a variable, and local machine is big-endian */
unsigned char *ptr = (unsigned char *)&UDP_PORT;
msg[25] = *ptr;
msg[26] = *(ptr + 1);
```

then:

```
/* if msg is a address variable */ 
unsigned short *ptr = (unsigned short *)(msg + 25);
int port = 0x0000FFFF & (unsigned short)*ptr;
```

Comment: This will only work if the endianness of the machine happens to be network byte order. On Intel CPUs it will mess up. Also, you meant `int port = 0x0000ffff & (unsigned short)*ptr;`

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this also .... for example iam showing as ...here i hv taken unsigned  buffer u can modify it according to your requirement ...

```
     unsigned char upBuff[3] = {0};
     upBuff[1] = att_seq_no & 0xff;
     upBuff[0] = att_seq_no >> 8;
     printf("Updated Sequence Number(For Attendance Record Table)(IN HEXA)\
                     Now is(IN HEXA) : %02x %02x\n", upBuff[0], upBuff[1]);
```